# How do I reduce the width of bars on histogram in Matlab

Tags: matlab, histogram, matlab-figure, matlab-guide

So far I have this;

```
Disp_X = X - mean(X);
hist(Disp_X);
h = hist(Disp_X); 

h.BinWidth = 0.001;
```

the `h.BinWidth` was working before to make my bars much narrower, but now I am getting this error message;

*"Field assignment to a non-structure array object."*

I don't really understand why that wasn't happening before, and now it is.

I am also having a bit of an issue trying to plot two histograms onto one plot. I have frequency of distance from mean in both x and y, and would like them to be plotted on the same graph.

Answer (score 4):

The command you want is `histogram` not `hist`.  `hist` is the old histogram that plots the output.  The outputs of that function are the counts and centers of the bins.  The output of `histogram` is a histogram object.

```
X = rand(1000,1);
Disp_X = X - mean(X);
h = histogram(Disp_X);
h.BinWidth = 0.001;
```

Then to add another histogram.

```
hold on
Y = rand(1000,1);
Dy = Y - mean(Y);
h2 = histogram(Dy);
```

Answer (score 2):

Matt's answer is correct if you are using R2014b or later, when `histogram` was introduced. If you are using an older version, then you can't use the dot notation and have to use `set`:

```
Disp_X = X - mean(X);
hist(Disp_X);
h = hist(Disp_X); 

set(h, 'BinWidth', 0.001);
```

Answer (score 2):

Both other answers are correct, but the simplest option will be to set this property while calling the function:

```
histogram(Disp_X,'BinWidth',0.001)
```